# Check if jQuery was blocked by a content filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website in which I include jquery.

```
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Sometimes, due to a content filter, the jquery-file won't be included. That's why I want to check with pure javascript, whether it has been included or not. How can I do this?

I already took a look on [Check if jQuery is included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810523/check-if-jquery-is-included), but it doesn't seem to help me in the right way.

Comment: So simple `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined')` doesn't work for u?

Comment: It works. Didn't know it was that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the following methods:

```
if (window.jQuery) {  
    // jQuery is loaded

} else {
    // jQuery is not loaded

}
```

or

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded

} else {
    // jQuery is loaded

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(typeof jQuery=='undefined') {
  //not included
} else {
     //JQueryCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
if(parseFloat($.fn.jquery) !== NaN)
{
  // jquery not available
}
```

`$.fn.jquery` returns jquery's version which is a float string. So we make use of that fact here.

Comment: It's not actually a float, but a string, e.g. it is `"1.9.1"` for version 1.9.1. Granted, `parseFloat()` will evaluate that as `1.9`, but I don't think referring to that value as a float is correct.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, yeah that was what I meant actually. Edited Thanks :)